# Creating an array from values of items returned from a selector?

Tags: jquery

I have the following selector:

```
var abc = $("input[id^= 'country']");
```

It returns details from five input checkboxes with names starting with country. What I want to do is to take the value of these checkboxes and put them into an array that's something like:

```
var array1 = ['true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'true'];
```

Is there an easy way to do this. I've tried all different combinations but without luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function.

```
var array1 = jQuery.map(abc, function (a) { return a.val(); });
```

Comment: oh i should add that I changed it to a.checked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
var array1 = $('input[id^= 'country']').map(function () {
  return this.attr("selected");
}).get();
```